# What is the simplest way of finding the distance between two pixels?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

This is maybe a bit of a noobish question - but say I want to find the distance between two pixels with coordinates (*x1,y1*) and (*x2,y2*). What would be the simplest way of doing this with MatLab?

Comment: [Pythagorean theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)

Comment: Hey there. I see you've gotten a lot of help recently but we have received no feedback from you with regards to our answers helping you.  If we have helped you, maybe if you accept some of our answers, it'll tell us that you no longer need any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) is an OK answer, but I would argue that it's slow (at least for a larger amount of points).  Also, `pdist` requires the statistics toolbox, so if you don't have that toolbox, you can't use that answer.

I would suggest using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) combined with [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) and [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) instead for a toolbox independent solution.  Assume that `X` is a 2 column matrix that is arranged in the following way:

```
X = [x y];
```

`x` and `y` are the X and Y coordinates of all of your points you want to find the distances to.  Therefore, each row consists of a single query point:

```
X2 = permute(X, [3 2 1]);
out = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, X, X2).^2, 2));
out = reshape(out, size(X,1), []);
```

This should give you the same output as applying `squareform` to the output of `pdist`.  Specifically, at element `(i,j)` of `out`, this will give you the distance between point `i` and point `j` and so the diagonal elements should give values of `0` as self-distances are 0.

## Suggestion by Jonas

We can avoid `reshape` which may be costly by replacing it with another `permute` call if we slightly change the way we `permute` the dimensions before calculating the distances:

```
out = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, permute(X, [1 3 2]), permute(X, [3 1 2])).^2, 3));
```

Comment: Or, with two permutes and no reshape: `out = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, permute(X, [1 3 2]), permute(X, 3 1 2)).^2, 3)`

Answer (score 3):

```
X = [x1,y1;x2,y2];
d = pdist(X,'euclidean')
```

d is distance.

Comment: So loop through all the pixels and apply this code?

Comment: @Zetland - No.  Simply place all of your points into a `N x 2` matrix where `N` is your total amount of points, and make that `X`.  After, use `pdist`.  BTW, I would suggest using `squareform` on this code so that it's transformed into a more readable format.